# Calculate data transferred in a local LAN

Tags: linux, router, gateway, network-traffic

How do you calculate the data flown between a computer and the gateway computer. I have a Linux router/gateway running IP Tables which routes internet traffic in a LAN. I have individual users with IP/MAC Address mapped who access Interet through the gateway computer. I would like to find out the traffic utilized by individual users.

Is it possible for us to find out what kind of traffic was HTTP, SMTP, FTP etc. Is it also possible to pool the information on hourly basis, and get specific info so that I can store information in a database?

I have heard of IP Accounting? Is that the right way

Answer (score 2):

I used to run `ntop` to do this.

You can also use accounting rules in iptables to track traffic. You can using [Accounting rules in Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/Accounting.html) to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of application which can calculate bandwidth. For example:

- Bmon
- Bandwidthd
- Bwbar
- bwm
- bwm-ng
- Cacti
- ipfm

You can alsto try to use Zabbix or Nagios with own scripts.